# Class 'Html' not found in YII2

Tags: php, html, class, yii2, fatal-error

Finally I try YII2 (can't move on from yii1) in my simple website project.
I've Fatal ERROR `Class 'Html' not found` in my views.

Case 1.
I put use `yii\helpers\Html;` in main (layout directory).
When I write `Html::img('@web/logo.jpg')` in index(view directory)I've got error `'html not found'.`

Case 2.
I write `Html::img('@web/logo.jpg')` in main (layout directory) running well.

case 3.
I delete `use yii\helpers\Html` in main (layout directory). and I write use `yii\helpers\Html in index` (view directory) running well, my image can show.

so, what's my mistake. Why I can't Html in index.

Answer (score 4):

Every single file needs to use fully qualified namespaces or have them as `use` declarations.

So every file where you are using `Html::...` needs to get this, not only layout file.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
yii\helpers\Html;
```

HTML provides a set of static methods for generating commonly used HTML tags.

Nearly all of the methods in this class allow setting additional html attributes for the html tags they generate. You can specify, for example, class, style or id for an html element using the $options parameter. See the documentation of the `tag()` method for more details.

Answer (score 0):

````
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>

<!DOChtml>TYPE 

<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>" class="h-100">```

 and continue with your page...........
````

Answer (score -2):

un comment short_open_tag and set value ON
after this change reset your web server, also use class element top of file

Comment: This answer lacks any type of context whatsoever.

Comment: @DeathWaltz are you reset web server? i have this problem and un comment short_open_tag in php.ini and fix issue

Comment: you never said anything about php.ini in your answer.